# Inflate exception binary xml file line #9

Tags: android, xml

I got inflate exception binary XML file line #9 while run the program. I don't know what is the problem here. the fragment class display in my main activity.   I got this exception while run my program.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}


public class MenuItems extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();

int[] img = { R.drawable.ice, R.drawable.idle, R.drawable.pongal };
String[] name = { "ice cream", "idle", "pongal" };

String sol = "";
int idnum;
DataBaseHandler db;

public static MenuItems newInstance() {
    MenuItems f = new MenuItems();
    return f;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        sol = name[i];
        // idnum=idnumber[i];

        //

        db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
        // get image from drawable
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                setImageResource(img[i]));

        // convert bitmap to byte
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Contact(sol, imageInByte));
        // display main List view bcard and contact name

        // Reading all contacts from database

        System.out.println(sol);
        System.out.println(setImageResource(img[i]));

    }

    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
                + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Result: ", log);
        // add contacts data in arrayList
        imageArry.add(cn);

    }

    View rootView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.firstscreen, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    MenuItemsListAdapter adapter = new MenuItemsListAdapter(getActivity(),
            imageArry);

    for (int a = 0; a < imageArry.size(); a++) {

        System.out.println("IndeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        System.out.println(imageArry.get(a));
    }

    return container;

}

private int setImageResource(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return i;
}

}

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class MenuItemsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<Contact>();

private Context context;

// private String[]number;
// private int[]imageid;

public MenuItemsListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Contact> data) {

    context = c;
    // this.imageid=imageid;
    // this.number=number;
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View list;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        list = new View(context);
        list = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstsub, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) list
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Contact picture = data.get(position);
        textView.setText(picture._name);
        // convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

        byte[] outImage = picture._image;
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                outImage);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    } else {
        list = (View) convertView;
    }
    return convertView;
}

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 My xml file here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </RelativeLayout>

   main activity xml file
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical" >


   <fragment
   android:layout_weight="8"
    android:name="com.example.balakrishnan.MenuItems"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add firstscreen.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Write all your code after you inflated xml for fragment i.e after this line

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.firstscreen, container, false);

    // Now write your code
 for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        sol = name[i];
        // idnum=idnumber[i];
```

Comment: Mr.Hulk i was change my code as per your advice. even it is not working.

Comment: is it the same exception still?

Comment: This is my main activity                                                                                                                                                             public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
 
    }